# How do I put a dialog div in form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dialog

I have a page where I've tried to put a JQuery dialog where data is entered and later goes to a server. The problem I've encountered is that the dialog is outside the `form` tag, since that whole data I enter is lost somewhere. It looks like this:
[image]

I've tried this so far:

```
var dialogAddPartDiv = $('.dialogAddPart'); 
$('form').append(dialogAddPartDiv);
```

But it only appends dialogAddPart, not its parents.

The command `$('form').append('.ui-dialog')` doesn't work in this case. How can I add the parent div of .dialogAddPart in form? The technology I use is XPages, since that I cannot use a inner button inside dialog declaration to proccess AJAX request, all that stuff is defined inside the XPage itself.

Comment: Wow, that's four quick upvotes in 2 minutes.  Guess inquiring minds want to know? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Dialog has an [appendTo](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option which allows you to append the dialog to some element:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  appendTo: "#someElem"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have tried `$('form').append('.ui-dialog')`, but this alone should not work.

Explicitly, you should try:

```
var uiDialog= $('.ui-dialog'); 
$('form').append(uiDialog);
```

Or, in a single line:

```
$('form').append($('.ui-dialog'));
```

You should consider giving unique id's to some of these elements, since you may in later end up having more than a single form element, for example.